# MVC 2 - JavaScript array to controller is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working in MVC2 and .net framework 3.5

While trying to pass a single object to mvc controller it is working fine. But when I try to pass the value as an array, I'm getting property values as null in the controller.

I'm using the below code to do this.

**JavaScript**

```
var tdmsConfiguredLayersList = [{Id:1,Name:'Test1'},{Id:2,Name:'Test2'}];
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            //JSON.stringify({ layers: tdmsConfiguredLayersList }),
            data:{layers:tdmsConfiguredLayersList},
            url: rootUrl + "Map/CatalogueDrawing",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
            },
            error: function (errResult) {
                debugger;
            }

    });
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public void CatalogueDrawing(List<LayerViewModel> layers)
{

}
```

[image: Result that is returned]

**LayerViewModel class**

```
public class LayerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your commened code was almost there. Your need to add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and use `data: JSON.stringify({ layers: tdmsConfiguredLayersList })`

Comment: I have tried that also. But it was not working

Comment: It does work :) (And assuming its `MapController`, then use `url:'@Url.Action("CatalogueDrawing", "Map")',` - don't hard code url's)

Comment: adding Content type and json.stringify will solve the issue in .net  4.0 and mvc4. Currently we are working in mvc 2 and .Net 3.5. When trying these in 3.5 layers object in controller is null

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2012/04/21/jsonvalueproviderfactory-in-mvc-2.aspx)_ - the paragraph on the `JsonValueProviderFactory` and also [this article](https://yobriefca.se/blog/2010/10/20/asp-dot-net-mvc3-jsonvalueproviderfactory/). Otherwise you may need to generate the data to use the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` - i.e. `data: { [0].Id: 1, [0].Name: 'Test1', [1].Id: 2, [1].Name: 'Test2' },`

Comment: thanks for the comments @Stephen Muecke. I have read that article and downloaded Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll and add that reference in my project. But it is not working.

Comment: Your code should works...just get rid of this line `dataType: "json",`

Comment: Then send the data as indexed values (2nd part of my last comment)

Comment: Tried that also Stephen... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to pass your list to controller in .net 3.5 was pass them as json string and deserialize it from controller

```
 using System.Web.Script.Serialization;



 var tdmsConfiguredLayersList = [{Id:1,Name:'Test1'},{Id:2,Name:'Test2'}];
  tdmsConfiguredLayersList = JSON.stringify(tdmsConfiguredLayersList);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { jsonString: tdmsConfiguredLayersList },
            url: rootUrl + "Map/CatalogueDrawing",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
            },
            error: function (errResult) {
                debugger;
            }

    });


public void CatalogueDrawing(string jsonString)
{
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<LayerViewModel> layers = jss.Deserialize<List<LayerViewModel>>(jsonString);
}
```